# How get ringer volume to auto adjust based on ambient noise level?

Tags: iphone, sound-volume, ios

My iPhone automatically adjust the screen brightness, based on the ambient light level. I want to do the same thing for my ringer volume: have it automatically adjusted based on the ambient noise level. In loud environments, I want a loud ringer. In quiet environments, I want a quiet ringer. Is there a way to do this? I searched for an app, but I found nothing.

Comment: That’s not a feature currently offered by Apple.  Your best bet is to leave a feature request at  https://apple.com/feedback

Comment: Tim want you to buy an Apple Watch thus you can get notified quietly.